# How to Create a Parent of Pages But have it not link yet keep the URL Path?

Tags: breadcrumb

I have the following menu structure:

```
About Us
 - Overview
 - Partners
```

What I would like is for the About Us parent to not have a page associated, aka no link, yet have the children/breadcrumbs still follow this path: site.com/about-us/overview. The issue is that it seems that in order for the children to have a proper breadcrumb path, the parent must be a page. Is there a workaround? Thanks.

Comment: The point of breadcrumbs is typically for each crumb to be a link. A better user experience might be to have About Us act as an 'index' page for its child pages, providing the user with a path through the content that matches the URL and breadcrumbs. Your menus could omit a link to that page, but then at least you have somewhere for your breadcrumbs to go. Alternatively you could make the About Us page the Overview page, and have Partners as the lone child page. If you have a dropdown menu you could simply add the parent page into the dropdown with "Overview" as the label.

Comment: Jacob there is no 'point' to breadcrumbs, but they are rather a tool that follows a particular structure. I'm looking for a solution outside the lines. As an example for Posts, you can create categories, and those categories are part of the path regardless of if the root parent is a page or not.

Comment: Of course there's a point to them. What a ridiculous thing to say. They're a navigational aid to tell the user where they are in a system. If some of the points in the breadcrumbs don't actually exist in the system then the whole concept is useless. But I think you're misusing the term "breadcrumbs". Breadcrumbs refers to the navigation interface of a trail of links representing the path to the current location. You appear to be just talking about the path component of the URL. While I'd argue that they serve a similar purpose they are handled entirely differently in WordPress.

Comment: To put this another way: What should ideally happen when a user tries to visit `site.com/about-us/`?

Comment: @swisspidy The goal is for nothing to happen; Essentially WP allows for 'custom' links' in the navigation, aka it could be an empty link, aka '#.' My problem is that I want to keep the breadcrumb structure of site.com/about-us, but WP won't allow that unless that sub-path leads to a page. (In Posts this is not an issue). If they for some reason try to manually navigate to site.com/about-us/, I want either nothing to happen, aka mimic a '#' url.